# ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode: Uncaught ReferenceError: ReactDOM is not defined

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I practice react
I met this error :  `Uncaught ReferenceError: ReactDOM is not defined`
when type `ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(document.body)` on chrome console

Please help me check the problem
I try the code on JSbin and works well,so I think it's webpack problem,but I have no idea .

And I notice there are many way write `React.render` part when I google ,what's the difference?? which one is correct??

```
React.render(<App name='Vipul' />,document.body); 
ReactDOM.render(<App name='Vipul' />,document.body);
React.renderComponents(<App name='Vipul' />,document.body);
```

Here is my code:

**main.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

console.log('Start')
var App = React.createClass({
  render: function(){
    console.log('render');
    return <h1 onClick={this.toggleState}>Hello</h1>
  },
  componentWillUnmount: function(){
  //在console執行 ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(document.body)
    console.log('componentWillUnmount');
  },

  toggleState: function(){
    this.setState({status: !this.state.status})
  }

});

ReactDOM.render(<App name='Vipul' />,document.body);
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
var WebpackNotifierPlugin = require('webpack-notifier');

module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/main.js",
    output: {
        filename: "./dist/bundle.js"
//        filename: "./public/dist/bundle.js"
    },
    plugins: [

    new WebpackNotifierPlugin()

  ],
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: "babel-loader",
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
                }
            }
        ]
    },devtool: 'source-map'
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ReactDOM available since 0.14.0, so

```
ReactDOM.render(<App name='Vipul' />,document.body);
```

should be fine. If you are using lower version of React then React.render

Secondly it is recommended not to render on document.body, rather create a div inside the body and render there.

> I met this error :  Uncaught ReferenceError: ReactDOM is not defined
>   when type ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(document.body) on chrome console

when you use Webpack the React and ReactDOM will not be available globally. So, this code will only work inside the file/module where you have imported React & ReactDOM.

Comment: Thank you. I got your point.  If  I use ````setTimeout(() => {
 ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(document.getElementById('app'));}, 10000);```` in my code. It works well!!! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is only one way to render React component in browser and it's this one:

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, target);
```

All other are deprecated - `renderComponent` is renamed to `render` and moved from `react` package to `react-dom` package.

Also, do you need to call `unmountComponentAtNode` in your `componentWillUnmount` lifecycle method? In your particular case it does not make sense. React will unmount component for you - for free.

`componentWillUnmount` usually serves for clearing timeouts/intervals and/or canceling async operations (Promises, closing connections, ...);

Removing that call won't harm you, try it out.

Comment: Thank you. I  use ````setTimeout(() => { ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(document.getElementById('app'));}, 10000);```` in my code. It works well!!!